# How to group elements in sequence using a particular column

Tags: ruby

I'm triying to concantenate this table by element name in sequence:

```
6x3+3+1;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+0;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
6x3+3+1;1x2+8+4;srgb(255,170,170)
1x2+7+5;1x2+8+4;srgb(255,170,170)
4x4+6+8;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
3x1+3+6;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x2+7+5;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+0;1x1+0+0;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;1x1+2+6;srgb(255,170,170)
3x1+3+6;1x1+2+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;1x1+1+10;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+1+10;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+0+11;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+2+11;srgb(255,170,170)
4x4+6+8;1x1+10+11;srgb(255,170,170)
```

I used this command:

```
  ruby -a -F';' -ne   '   sum= {};sum[$F[1]] ||= ""  ;  sum[$F[1]]  =  $F[0] +   sum[$F[1]];  puts sum[$F[1]]     '   ZmGHmmzb
```

and obtained:

```
6x3+3+1
1x8+1+2
1x1+1+0
6x3+3+1
1x2+7+5
4x4+6+8
3x1+3+6
1x2+7+5
1x1+1+0
1x8+1+2
3x1+3+6
1x8+1+2
1x1+1+11
1x1+1+11
1x1+1+11
4x4+6+8
```

But I expected this:

```
6x3+3+1 1x8+1+2 1x1+1+0
6x3+3+1 1x2+7+5
4x4+6+8 3x1+3+6 1x2+7+5
1x1+1+0
1x8+1+2 3x1+3+6
1x8+1+2 1x1+1+11
1x1+1+11 1x1+1+11 4x4+6+8
```

My command not concatenate the string based on column 2. Why?

Comment: You should probably post a full Ruby program instead of a one-liner snippet. Nobody is going to take the time to try to figure out what your one-liner does.

Comment: I use oneliners for save time writing code

Comment: Please, please, please. **STOP USING ONE-LINERS**. This is not saving any time because I see you coming here again and again with questions relating to them where if you'd taken the five minutes to put this into a properly organized Ruby file mistakes would be more obvious and therefore more fixable. This code is a nightmare to work with. It's a nightmare to help you with. There's literally no reason to do this.

Comment: sorry;What happens is that I have another program other than ruby that works using oneliners and I did not want to waste time using data binding so I had to be forced to use oneliner; But luckily I already have the answer to this problem

Comment: Ruby is a highly expressive language that allows programs to be extremely readable, where control flow is made abundantly clear, and the intent of each method or variable is self-explanatory. You throw all that out the window when you do this, where variables like `$F` could be anything and control-flow can only be discerned with careful examination of your code. Doing this once or twice for lack of knowing better is fine. Insisting on doing it because it "saves time" is nothing but frustrating, I'm sorry. Ruby is not `sed`. Stop treating it like it is.

Comment: "I use oneliners for save time writing code". The time you lose debugging overwhelms any minor saving writing a one-liner could generate. You're arguing with extremely experienced programmers when you should be accepting their advice.

Comment: Read Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)", "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)", "[Rubber Duck Problem Solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)", and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". If you ask and find a solution within 29 minutes you didn't do enough research and didn't try hard enough before you asked your question.

Comment: Sorry for the question will not post again questions like this one

Comment: This question could have been made a lot better if you took the small amount of time to rework that code into a proper Ruby program, one that anyone can read and understand, and explained the requirements a tiny bit better. It's not a huge jump. Look at Ron Skeet's advice and I'm sure you'll get the hang of it and then you'll find help a lot easier to come by. Sorry I'm so hard on you here, but this is code that calls for an intervention before you end up trapped in your own bad habits.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry - you don't owe us anything. It's just that really, one-liners in Ruby are rather confusion-makers than time-savers.

Comment: Ok take the advice from now publish ruby script correctly

Comment: Why is `1x1+1+11 1x1+1+11 4x4+6+8` expected? The values in the second column don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
data = DATA.readlines.map { |l| l.split(';')[0, 2] }

data.group_by { |l| l[1] }.values.map { |a| a.map(&:first) }
# => [["6x3+3+1", "1x8+1+2", "1x1+1+0"],
#     ["6x3+3+1", "1x2+7+5"],
#     ["4x4+6+8", "3x1+3+6", "1x2+7+5"],
#     ["1x1+1+0"],
#     ["1x8+1+2", "3x1+3+6"],
#     ["1x8+1+2", "1x1+1+11"],
#     ["1x1+1+11"],
#     ["1x1+1+11"],
#     ["4x4+6+8"]]

__END__
6x3+3+1;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+0;2x1+1+1;srgb(255,170,170)
6x3+3+1;1x2+8+4;srgb(255,170,170)
1x2+7+5;1x2+8+4;srgb(255,170,170)
4x4+6+8;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
3x1+3+6;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x2+7+5;1x2+6+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+0;1x1+0+0;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;1x1+2+6;srgb(255,170,170)
3x1+3+6;1x1+2+6;srgb(255,170,170)
1x8+1+2;1x1+1+10;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+1+10;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+0+11;srgb(255,170,170)
1x1+1+11;1x1+2+11;srgb(255,170,170)
4x4+6+8;1x1+10+11;srgb(255,170,170)
```

The heavy lifting is done by `group_by`. Obviously there are other ways to do it, but `group_by` is a good fit when you want to "group data by some value". It's up to you to figure out how to output the data in the form you want.

Comment: It's important to sketch out code in a normal form before trying to convert it to a "one-liner". One-line, command-lines are not that useful because Ruby can easily treat a script as part of a pipeline. You can do very complex tasks in a regular script, but still call it as part of a chain of commands. Read about ARGF and OptionParser.